# Distance measure that constrains a walk over land and accounts for the shape of the Earth

Tags: r

Are there distance measures that constrain a walk over land (even across multiple continents) and account for the shape of the Earth?

I have been using the Vincenty-Ellipsoid distance in `R` in package `geosphere`, but it is not appropriate, because for distances between points across bodies of water or along weird shapes such as the distance between Yemen and the southern tip of India (where traveling across water is precluded), the ’Vincenty’ (ellipsoid) great circle distance only gives you "as the crow flies" distances over water, and the crow is not constrained to flying over land.

I am prepared to measure my starting point great circle distance from Yemen to a waypoint like Baghdad, Iraq; then a next step distance between Baghdad, Iraq, to another waypoint like Nagpur in central India; then the next step distance between Nagpur, India, and the southern tip of India.

However, this seems clunky and prone to bias, especially if I want to also constrain the possible route to elevations less than 2000m.

I work solely in R, but I can sometimes turn Python scripts into R code.

Comment: Try and keep the title of your question related to the text in the body of your question. After asking that in your first paragraph, you then go on to something else unrelated to what a great circle distance is, ie a constrained distance calculation.

Comment: @Spacedman Thanks, should I change the title, or am I stuck with a bad title? I'm happy to change it something like "Can I use the ’Vincenty’ (ellipsoid) great circle distance to constrain travel to land only?"

Comment: Either edit out everything past your first paragraph so its just about whether the Vincenty distance is a straight-line measure, and keep the title, or change the title to asking about how to compute a travel distance across land, or with other constraints etc etc, and edit the bit about Vincenty distances out because that's not relevant. But also you should search your favourite GIS literature (and the iinternet) for distance measures and path finding since these things are well documented elsewhere.

Comment: @Spacedman I changed the title and updated the body of the post to clarify, especially since you answered my first question that the Vincenty Ellipsoid distance is not constrained to lan, which was helpful.

Comment: How accuate do you need the paths traversable by people? Do you want actual routing or do you want "the shortest lines between point A and B that are inside the polygons of earth landmass"?

Comment: @til_b I am representing human migration out of Africa and throughout the globe, so other than crossing continents at set waypoints (like passing out of Africa via Cairo, Egypt and passing from Siberia to North America via Anadyr, Russia) and staying in paths below 2000m in elevation, the accuracy is not vital because people could have used multiple routes to get to the same place. I would say, yes, more "the shortest lines between point A and B that are inside the polygons of Earth's landmasses".

Comment: one solution could be to use a cost distance analysis where your cost raster is set to 1 for walkable area and to no data for obstacles (sea and above 2000m in your case) effectively preventing crossing

Comment: @J.R From a raster with 30,000 points across the entire world, I converted the raster to points, then to sf objects. I found which points fall on land and kept only those points. I found the elevation and removed all points with elevation < 0 and > 2000m. I rasterized Long/Lat decimals of remaining points and filled the values of the raster with the elevation. I created a transition layer: ```tr1 <- transition(r_data, transitionFunction = function(x){1}, directions = 8) ##uses Moore neighborhood```, where the cost going from one cell to an adjacent cell is 1.

Comment: @J.R I then geocorrected: ```h8 <- geoCorrection(tr1,  scl=FALSE)```. Now, I want to have the length of an edge connecting two vertices to be the Vincenty Ellipsoid distance, and I want the shortest path from one location to another to follow Dijkstra's algorithm. I am unclear if I the ```shortestPath``` function in ```gdistance``` or ```shortest_paths``` function in ```igraph``` is a distance function or a path function or both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a Stanford computer science paper from 1992 that describes an algorithm: https://graphics.stanford.edu/courses/cs268-09-winter/notes/handout7.pdf . Unfortunately the coding is left to the reader. You could "just" implement that and use a haversine distance measurement instead of euclidean distances.

Google keywords were "shortest path inside a polygon", maybe you find code with that too.

Additionally you could search for 2d visibility analysis code, which can be applied to your problem.

Last, to constrain to "below 2000m" you would need to amend your landmass polygons by subtracting (creating holes) of areas that are >2000m in elevation and see if the code you end up using can deal with polygons with holes (often called "donut shape").

In [Finding shortest path while avoiding polygon features](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/12247/finding-shortest-path-while-avoiding-polygon-features) they suggest using cost path analysis on raster datasets.

I found Guibas, L. J., & Hershberger, J. (1989). Optimal shortest path queries in a simple polygon. In Journal of Computer and System Sciences (Vol. 39, Issue 2, pp. 126–152). Elsevier BV. https://doi.org/10.1016/0022-0000(89)90041-x  but did not read it.

Then there is https://fribbels.github.io/shortestpath/writeup.html (code here: https://github.com/fribbels/fribbels.github.io/tree/master/shortestpath ), which is probably closest to a reusable codebase. The code for their visibility graph demo is at https://github.com/fribbels/fribbels.github.io/blob/master/shortestpath/visgraph.js .